# Не могу установить Symfony2

Tags: php

Сижу на денвере (PHP Version 5.3.3).

А проблема в том, что не могу установить `symfony2`, после прохода в `web/check.php` выдает 1 ошибку и рекомендацию, так понял включить поддержку `pdo_sql`, лезу в `php.ini` снимаю коменты рестарю... ноль эмоций о_О, ищу в инете, нашел, но там линь.

[Решение проблемы с symfony 2: You need to enable either the SQLite or PDO_SQLite extension for the profiler to run properly](http://wel.org.ua/web/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-symfony-2-enable-sqlite-pdo_sqlite-extension-profiler-run-properly).

**В принципе вот сама проблема вывод:**

> `Welcome to your new Symfony project.`
>
> `This script will guide you through the basic configuration of your project. You can also do the same by editing the вЂ�app/config/parameters.iniвЂ™ file directly.
> 1 Major problems`
>
> `Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:`
>
> `Install and enable the SQLite3 or PDO_SQLite extension.`
>
> `Recommendations`
>
> `Additionally, to enhance your Symfony experience, itвЂ™s recommended that you fix the following:`
>
> `Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended).
> Install and enable the intl extension.
> Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.`
>
> `* Changes to the php.ini file must be done in "Z:\usr\local\php5\php.ini".`

Пните, что ли куда рыть?

Comment: есть такие .. php_sqlite.dll php_pdo.dll я добавил php_sqlite3.dll ..

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, а есть ли вообще модуль `PDO_SQLite` в папке расширений. А то иногда включают, а его нет на месте. Потом проверьте, включен ли он - посмотрите через `phpinfo()` и включите все таки `short_open_tag`.

Comment: Решил проблему ..скачал дополнительные расширения с сайта denwer!